# mapping AnnotationAssertion into an owl:Class

Tags: java, parsing, mapping, rdf, owl

I would like to change the structure of this RDF file and save it in OWL file, but i have big data thus i should write a program, which do this automatically.
Any idea how could i map the annotation `name` to an `owl:Class` in java and which java library i need to download?

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.onto-service.com/test.xml#co_67">    <j.0:qCount>2</j.0:qCount>
    <j.0:name>vendor</j.0:name>
    <j.0:mDate>2014-10-03T11:17:56</j.0:mDate>
    <j.0:color>0080FF</j.0:color>
    <j.0:cDate>2014-10-02T19:53:25</j.0:cDate>
    <j.0:cCount>2</j.0:cCount>
    <j.0:au>Super</j.0:au>
</rdf:Description>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  The RDF snippet you've shown us contains a triple `<http://...#co_67> j.0:name "vendors (hardware, software)"`.  The object of that triple is a string, not a class.  What you *could* do, I suppose, is define `j.0:name` as a datatype property, and then add an axiom that says "if x has "vendors ..." as a value for j.0:name, then x belongs to the class Vendors".  To do that, though, you'd need to declare j.0:name as a datatype property, and to declare a class Vendors.

Comment: thanks, you get the idea, but how could i do this in java?

Comment: In Java? The question sounded like you wanted to do this in Protege.  What is it that you want to do in Java?  Define the ontology that I described?  That would be easier to do in Protege.  You could certainly use a SPARQL query to *transform* the data that you have into the data that you want, but you'll need to make the problem more specific if that's what you want to do.  Stack Overflow works best with specific well-defined programming problems.

Comment: i have big data in this format thus that´way i would like to map it with a java program

Comment: That doesn't really clarify what you want.  Do you want a Java program that produces an ontology that you can load into Protege *in addition* to your original data and that a reasoner can use to put things in classes?  Do you want a Java program that takes your data as input and outputs a new file that contains everything?  You have not yet provided a specific programming problem.

Comment: I don't know what an `owl:annotationAssesment` is, and the snippet you've shown doesn't declare `j.0:name` as an `owl:AnnotationProperty`. (I assume that you meant `owl:annotationAssertion` rather than `owl:annotationAssessment`.)  It's not clear whether you have raw RDF (i.e., non-OWL) coming in and Protege is *assuming* that a property not declared as an object property or a data type property is an annotation property, or if you've actually got OWL where j.0:name is declared as an annotation property.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the guidelines for questions, which mention that *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*  Aim to present the minimal input and sample output that show what you want.  If you can't do it by hand, you won't be able to program it.